# Doubt in corollary of Green's theorem: How can we say $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} > 0$ in a region!

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem

> If $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} > 0$ at a point $P$ then how can we say $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} > 0$ in some region surrounding $P$.

text books says - continuity of derivatives. I just know that if F is differentiable then it is continuous. I did not understand how $> 0$ at Point $P$ translates to $> 0$ in some region around $P$

Comment: What are the conditions on $N$ and $M$? I'm pretty sure that they are supposed to be $C^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb R ^n \to \mathbb R$ be some continuous function. Suppose we know $f(x) > 0$ for some $x \in \mathbb R ^n$. 
By continuity (choosing $\varepsilon = \frac{f(x)}{2}$) there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y$ with $\lVert x - y \rVert < \delta$ we have $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \delta$. Thus for these $y$ we have $f(y) > \varepsilon = \frac {f(x)}{2} > 0$ (by the triangle inequality). Thus if $f(x) >0$ we also have that $f$ is greater than $0$ on a region surrounding $x$.

Now take $f = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} $. Then $f$ is continuous (if $N,M \in \mathcal C ^1$) and $f(P) > 0 $. The above reasoning yields that $f$ is greater that $0$ on some region surrounding $P$.

Comment: $f(y) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(y) + \epsilon, $

$f(x)>0 \implies f(y) + \epsilon > f(x) >0$. If $f(y) +\epsilon > 0$ how can we say $f(y) >0 ???$ 

other part i understood

Comment: If $f(y) \geq f(x) > 0$ there is nothing to show, otherwise $\frac{f(x)}{2} >  \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = f(x) -f(y)$. Rearranging yields $f(y) > \frac{f(x)}{2} > 0$. So its not really triangle inequality, rather a by case analysis.

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon \implies f(y) + \epsilon > f(x) >0 \implies f(y)+ \epsilon > 0 . $choose $ \epsilon = 0.1, f(y) =-0.01$ i mean i did not understand how it ensures f(y)>0

Comment: In my comment I showed you how it ensures $f(y) > 0$. Note that we chose $\varepsilon = \frac{f(x)}{2}$. Rearrange $f(y) + \varepsilon = f(y) + \frac{f(x)}{2} > f(x) $ to get $f(y) > \frac{f(x)}{2}$.

Comment: got it... thanks a lot . can you pls clarify my other doubt?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510423/error-in-calculating-i-iint-s-2x2-y2ds-over-cylinder

I started learning chapter. so i am getting basic doubts